# Looking for assistance with Pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I need some help with pseudocode. The question is as follows:

> Write pseudocode for a function, processPayment() that processes
>   payment by customers and commits the system to delivering the promised
>   product and service. This function may call on other functions,
>   possibly from other objects.  You do not have to describe the called
>   functions or the classes that they belong to as long the calls are
>   reasonably explanatory.
>
> Advertising is displayed while the customer
>   awaits credit approval. (i.e., you can assume that while the function
>   is waiting for credit card approval to complete, the next step begins
>   immediately.)
>
> Advertising is removed as soon as credit acceptance or
>   denial is received. You can assume that the user has already entered
>   credit card information and is aware of the costs of each option.

I have this as pseudocode:

```
processPayment() 
   do displayAdContent(); 
   while paymentConfirmation(bool) = false;
```

I keep thinking I need something after processPayment(). Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a lot more than "something after processPayment()." I would do something like this:

```
ProcessPayment()
{
   if(paymentIsValid) 
   {
      do displayAdContent();

      if(isInInventory()) 
      {
         try 
         {
            do createAndChargeOrder();
            do deliverProduct(); 
            do updateInventory();
         }
         catch
         {
            do cancelOrder();
            do sendFailedOrderNotification();  
         }
      }
      else
      {
         do notifyNotAvailable();
         do offerSimilarProduct();
      }

      do sendConfirmation();
   }
   else
   {
      do paymentNotValid();
   }
}
```